# Understanding the upper bound for an $d$-dimensional integral in a paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration

At the moment I am reading the paper "Effective pair interaction between impurity particles induced by a dense Fermi gas" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02841) and trying to understand a certain computation, which one can find on page 27:

For $k_F>0$
$$\int_{\mid k \mid \leq k_F} \text{d}^d k \int_{\mid l+k \mid \geq k_F} \text{d}^d l \ \frac{1}{(1+\mid l\mid^2)^2} \lesssim \int_0^{k_F}\text{d}^d s \ s^{d-1} \int_{k_F-s}^{\infty}\text{d} r \ (1+r)^{-2} \lesssim k_F^{d-1}\, .$$

I suppose here they used a coordinate transformation into spherical coordinates (or at least for the first integral $\int_{\mid k \mid \leq k_F} \text{d}^d k$). But I don't know how to handle the second integral.

Comment: The inequality (124) in the article really looks unreasonable.

Comment: @Gec What makes you think that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the inner integral diverges at a sufficiently large $d$ if there is no ultraviolet cutoff. Using the triangle inequality it easy to show that for any $l$ such that $|l+k| \geq k_F$ the inequality $|l| \geq k_F - |k|$ holds, and for any $l$ such that $|l| \geq k_F + |k|$ the inequality $|l+k| \geq k_F$ is valid. Hence upper and lower bounds for the inner integral:
$$
\int_{|l| \geq k_F + |k|} d^dl\ \frac1{(1+|l|^2)^2} \leq \int_{|l+k| \geq k_F} d^dl\ \frac1{(1+|l|^2)^2} \leq \int_{|l| \geq k_F - |k|} d^dl\ \frac1{(1+|l|^2)^2}
$$
The lower bound integral diverges for $d \geq 4$. Do the authors of the article consider the case of $d\leq 3$?

**Update** To finish with required asymptotic formula. For $d = 1, 2, 3$, the upper bound integral converges, and we can proceed as follows. First, we have
$$
\int_{|l| \geq k_F - |k|} d^dl\ \frac1{(1+|l|^2)^2} = A_d \int_{k_F - |k|}^\infty dr \frac{r^{d-1}}{(1 + r^2)^2},
$$
where $A_d$ are known constants $\sim k_F^0\sim 1$. For $d = 1,2,3$ and for all positive $r$ holds
$$
\frac{r^{d-1}}{(1 + r^2)^2} \leq \frac{B_d}{(1+r)^2}
$$
where $B_d$ are constants $\sim k_F^0 \sim 1$. Now, we have
$$
\int_{|l+k| \geq k_F} d^dl\ \frac1{(1+|l|^2)^2} \leq A_d B_d\int_{k_F - |k|}^\infty dr \frac{1}{(1 + r)^2}.
$$
and for the initial integral
$$
\int_{|k| < k_F} d^d k
\int_{|l+k| \geq k_F} d^dl\ \frac1{(1+|l|^2)^2} \leq A_d^2B_d \int_0^{k_F} ds\ s^{d-1}\int_{k_F - s}^\infty dr \frac1{(1 + r)^2} \lesssim
$$
$$
\lesssim \int_0^{k_F} ds\ s^{d-1}\int_{k_F - s}^\infty dr \frac1{(1 + r)^2} = \int_0^{k_F} ds\ s^{d-1} \frac1{1 + k_F - s} = k_F^{d-1} \int_0^1 dx\ \frac{(1-x)^{d-1}}{x + 1/k_F}
$$
In my opinion, the most recent integral is $\sim k_F^{d-1}\ln k_F$ for $k_F\gg 1$ and $\sim k_F^d$ for $k_F \ll 1$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. You are right, in their theorems they consider $d\in \{1,2,3\}$, but at one point claim, that higher dimensions should work "similarly"

Comment: @uzizi_1 I finished derivation for the case $d \leq 3$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you mind telling me if your first equation, the one with the constant $A_d$ has a name, is a certain integral theorem or where to look it up?

Comment: @uzizi_1 I don't know the name of this theorem. Multidimensional integrals of spherically  symmetric  functions, that is, depending only on the modulus of the vector, and not on the angles, are expressed as one-dimensional integrals:: $\int \ d^dr f(|r|) = A_d \int_0^\infty dR\ R^{d-1} f(R)$, where $A_d = 2\pi^{d/2}/\Gamma(d/2)$ is the area of the unit radius sphere.